# SQL Server query to convert Date to Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a **query :**

> `Select Cast(Datediff(MINUTE, '19700101', Cast(GETDATE() As date)) As bigint) *60000 + Datediff(ms, '19000101', Cast(GETDATE() As time));`

which gives the **output :**

```
1395065961607
```

In **Java**,

```
Date d = new Date(1395065961607L);
```

The **Output is :**

```
Mon Mar 17 **22**:19:21 MYT 2014
```

But My **output should be :**

```
Mon Mar 17 **14**:19:21 MYT 2014
```

How can i achieve this in query?

Comment: that's what I'm talking about. I believe you should look into timezones here

Comment: Select Cast(Datediff(MINUTE, '19700101', Cast(GETDATE() As date)) As bigint) *60000+ Datediff(ms, '19000101', Cast('2014-03-10 15:10:10.989' As time))-8*60*60*1000; This works to be fine

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is account for Java's standard base time (known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT) with regard to your calculation. The key element of Java's standard base time is the "GMT" timezone, which you did not account for in your original post above.

So with that in mind, you have to account for 'the epoch' versus your local timezone's current moment in time as follows:

```
SELECT (Cast(DateDiff(day, Cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' AS datetimeoffset), SysDateTimeOffset()) AS bigint) * 86400000)
       + DateDiff(millisecond, DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, Cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' AS datetimeoffset), SysDateTimeOffset()), Cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00' AS datetimeoffset)), SysDateTimeOffset())
```

I hope this helps.